# how to change and load content in javafx webview dynamically?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

i am experimenting with JavaFX `WebView` to make it a rich text editor, which can be set editable(true/false) and it's content can be styled . I have a `EditableWebView` class which extends a `StackPane` and `WebView` is added into it as a child. Now i am inheriting this class with two Other classes `ChatInputEditor` and `TranscriptWindow`. In main application class I am adding them into a `SplitPane` and i wish to work them as sender and receiver correspondingly. But `loadContent("")` is not helping in loading content to receiver. Below is my code ...

```
public class EditableWebView extends StackPane {

    private final WebView editor = new WebView();
    private final WebEngine engine = editor.getEngine();
    private final BooleanProperty editable = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private final StringProperty textProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();

    private String contentEditable = "<body bgcolor='cornsilk' "
            + "onLoad='document.body.focus();' "
            + "contenteditable='true'/>";

    private String content = "<body bgcolor='aqua' "
            + "onLoad='document.body.focus();' />";

    private String contents = "";

    public EditableWebView() {
        editable.addListener((obs, old, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                engine.loadContent(contentEditable);
                engine.executeScript("document.body.focus()");
                editor.requestFocus();
            }
        });

        textProperty.addListener((observable, oldString, newString) -> {

        });

        engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((ov, oldState, newState) -> {
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {

            }
        });

        getChildren().add(editor);
    }

    public WebView getEditor() {
        return editor;
    }

    public WebEngine getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }

    public void clearEditor() {
        engine.loadContent(contentEditable);
    }

    public void clearView() {
        engine.loadContent(content);
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return (String) engine.executeScript("document.documentElement.innerHTML");
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        engine.loadContent(content);
    }

    public final void setEditable(Boolean value) {
        editable.set(value);
    }

    public final Boolean getEditable() {
        return editable.get();
    }

    public final BooleanProperty editableProperty() {
        return editable;
    }
}
```

Below is my editable editor class which is acting like a sender

```
public class ChatInputEditor extends EditableWebView{
    private Message msg = Message.getInstance();
    private TranscriptWindow tw = TranscriptWindow.getInstance();

    public ChatInputEditor(){
        this.setEditable(true); 

        this.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent event) -> {
            if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER){
                String mesg = getContent();
                msg.setMessage(mesg); 
                tw.setRcvd(true); 
                this.clearEditor();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the Non-editable editor which acts like receiver

```
public class TranscriptWindow extends EditableWebView{

    private Message msg = Message.getInstance();
    private BooleanProperty rcvd = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    private static TranscriptWindow singleton;
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    public static TranscriptWindow getInstance() {
        // Synchronize on LOCK to ensure that we don't end up creating two singletons.
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            if (null == singleton) {
                TranscriptWindow controller = new TranscriptWindow();
                singleton = controller;
            }
        }
        return singleton;
    }

    public TranscriptWindow(){        
        rcvd.addListener((obs,old,newValue)->{
            if(newValue){
                System.out.println("receiving");
                String mesg = msg.getMessage();
                setContent(mesg);
                rcvd.set(false); 
            }
        });
    }

    public final void setRcvd(Boolean value) {
        rcvd.set(value);
    }

    public final Boolean getRcvd() {
        return rcvd.get();
    }

    public final BooleanProperty rcvdProperty() {
        return rcvd;
    }
}
```

Message is a simple POJO class with getter and setter

```
public class Message {
    private String message;

    private static Message singleton;
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    public static Message getInstance() {
        // Synchronize on LOCK to ensure that we don't end up creating two singletons.
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            if (null == singleton) {
                Message controller = new Message();
                singleton = controller;
            }
        }
        return singleton;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Finally here is my application class

```
public class EditableWebViewTry extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        SplitPane pane = new SplitPane(); 
        pane.setDividerPositions(0.70); 
        pane.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL); 
        pane.getItems().add(new TranscriptWindow());
        pane.getItems().add(new ChatInputEditor());
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setScene(scene); 
        stage.setHeight(300); 
        stage.setWidth(200); 
        stage.show();   
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

The problem i am facing right now is i cannot set content to another instance of WebView from it's one instance. I have already went through lots of content on web for this, but found no help. I am a newbie here and for javafx also. So please help me. Thanks in advance.